# How to append to the last line of a file in c++?

Tags: c++

using g++, I want to append some data to the last line (but to not create a new line) of a file. Probably, a good idea would be to move back the cursor to skip the '\n' character in the existing file. However this code does not work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("file.dat", fstream::app|fstream::out);

myfile.seekp(-1,myfile.ios::end); //I believe, I am just before the last '\n' now
cout << myfile.tellp() << endl; //indicates the position set above correctly

myfile << "just added"; //places the text IN A NEW LINE :(
//myfile.write("just added",10); //also, does not work correctly
myfile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Please give me the idea of correcting the code. Thank you in advance. Marek.

Comment: There is not necessarily a new line at the end. And a "new line" does not necessarily take just one character (typically `0x0D, 0x0A` on Windows).

Comment: You'd be better off opening the file at the beginning, reading the content, and thereby interpreting what the content of the last line is (and how/if it is terminated).  Then your program can decide how to append your additional data.  (Also, for safety, consider creating a new file, rather than directly overwriting the original - then, once writing the data has occurred, delete the original and rename the new file as needed).

Comment: Thank you. I am thinking of reading data from the last line of the data file into a buffer and transforming it. However, this approach seems less elegant to me, especially considering that these are large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

When you open with `app`, writing always writes at the end, regardless of what `tellp` tells you.
("app" is for "append", which does not mean "write in an arbitrary location".)

You want `ate` (one of the more inscrutable names in C++) which seeks to the end only immediately after opening.
You also want to add that final newline, if you want to keep it.
And you probably also want to check that the last character *is* a newline before overwriting it.
*And*, seeking by characters can do strange things in text mode, *and* if you open in binary mode you need to worry about the platforms's newline convention.

Manipulating text is much harder than you think.

(And by the way, you don't need to specify `out` on an `ofstream` - the "o" in "ofstream" takes care of that.)

Comment: Yes, I need 'ate', indeed, thank you!
I am aware of differences in number of chars ending the lines in lin/win systems and of some difficulties with universality, however I just need this script to transform my data.
So now I replaced the lines by
`myfile.open ("file.dat", fstream::ate);
myfile.seekp(-5,ios::end);`
to check if I am able to add some text (somewhere) into the last line. Unfortunately, in this case, all data from the file are erased, no matter what is the number
...seekp(-5 <----
Have I forgotten to add something?

Comment: @Marek You can't *insert* data into a file, you can only overwrite the existing data or add data at the end. You need to read whatever you want to keep and then write it again after the stuff you added.